# ASP.net web TextChangedEvent not firing

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, web, textbox

I'm trying to make a website with some fun features that require a working `TextChanged` event with textboxes. Here's what I tried to do:

Textbox html code

C# embedded code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.TextChanged += TextBox1_TextChanged;
}

protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime time = new DateTime();

    try
    {
        int textBoxValue = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
        Label2.Text = "valid" + time.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
    }
    catch
    {
        Label2.Text = "test";
        TextBox1.Text = "1";
    }
}
```

https://pastebin.com/mAyKMLE5 also contains some html code.

Somehow I think it's not registering any textChangedEvents at all. I'm thinking the page has to actually reload for it to register it? Anyway, I hope someone could help me out. If you need additional information about the problem I'll gladly give it.

Thanks in advance,
DutchJelly

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2589b44c.aspx

Comment: Are you aware it only fires on a postback? I think you might expect it to fire as someone types?

Comment: I'm very new to webdevelopment. Actually, I started today. Thanks for sending me the link to useful documents.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `AutoPostBack = true` programmatically also if it is not present on the TextBox already.

```
TextBox1.TextChanged += TextBox1_TextChanged;
TextBox1.AutoPostBack = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Style="margin-top: 0px" Width="32px" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="True" Font-Size="Small" Height="16px">1</asp:TextBox>
```

Add `AutoPostBack="True"` in your textbox

Comment: Welcome.. Accept as answer :)

Comment: @jellekeulemans you really want to post back on every typed letter? Usually you use ajax/xhr for that.

Comment: My rep is too low :P

Comment: @DinkarVeer I guess that's your opinion but I doubt many would agree that constant postbacks is very good option.

Comment: Oh I'm too new for ajax. I'm just trying to get something to work.

Comment: @jellekeulemans you will have to wait for the whole page to round-trip between each letter. If it works for you, great, but ajax isn't hard so don't be intimidated.

Comment: when the event currently gets fired is when the textbox is unfocused. Will it update instantly with ajax?

Comment: Oh I just realized that it simply takes some time for it to update.. I'll try to get into Ajax I guess. Thanks for the advice @DinkarVeer